# Cant go back to Ubuntu 16.04 after going back to Windows 8.1

Tags: dual-boot

I went to Windows 8.1 by pressing F2  during the restart. I then couldnt find a way to return to Ubuntu which I installed alongside Windows 8.1.

Comment: Is Windows' Fast-Boot disabled? And are Win and Ubuntu installed in UEFI (if available) or Legacy BIOS mode?